# CNContactStore Save Error

Tags: swift, error-handling, contacts, swift2

CNContactStore's `executeSaveRequest(_:)` method throws an error according to the documentation.

I am trying to catch this error in a `do/catch`, but I cannot figure out what error I need to catch.

```
do{
  try store.executeSaveRequest(saveRequest)
} catch *???* {
  //alert the user
}
```

What is supposed to replace the ???'s in the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options actually.

Catch any error without knowing the error

`catch {...}`

2. Catch any error with the specific error message

`catch let error { // Use error }`

3. Use [exhaustive catch clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30720807/3810673) to handle specific errors using the `CNErrorCode` enum.

   ```
   enum CNErrorCode : Int {

       case CommunicationError
       case DataAccessError

       case AuthorizationDenied

       case RecordDoesNotExist
       case InsertedRecordAlreadyExists
       case ContainmentCycle
       case ContainmentScope
       case ParentRecordDoesNotExist

       case ValidationMultipleErrors
       case ValidationTypeMismatch
       case ValidationConfigurationError

       case PredicateInvalid

       case PolicyViolation
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Where did you happen to find the CNErrorCodes, though? I looked all over the documentation and couldn't find them.

Comment: I couldn't find them either. I just typed CNErrorCode in Xcode and command clicked it