# swift parse query skip null column

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm doing a `PFQuery` to get uploaded file in column. How to get that file and if the column is null there's no file do something else ?

If the column is null i'm getting error message the query wont go well.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping on Optional value

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil
            {
                for object in objects! {
                    self.files.append(object.objectForKey("file") as! PFFile)     
                }
```

I want to get that file but if the column was null do something else ? how can i do that?

Comment: Could you post the exact error message to help other users?

Comment: @Juzzbott I did, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use optional unwrapping with if let file = ... as? PFFile {

} else {

}

Comment: I've did that but i'm getting error : Pattern matching in a condition requires the 'case' keyword , Any help ?

Comment: are u using swift 2.0 or 1.2?

Comment: in swift 2.0 error handling is introduced so u must catch all possible errors (for example make do loop with catch and handle all errors) -> related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720497/swift-do-try-catch-syntax

Comment: There's no other way to do it ?

Comment: well in swift 2.0 no ... in < 2.0 u can use optional unwrapping for checking for nil values