# Throwing swift error with specific error type in method signature

Tags: ios, swift, exception

With the new swift [error handling](http://umentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) introduced in 2.1 is it possible to specify a given `ErrorType` a method will throw?

e.g.
`class func nextOrderDate() throws OrderError -> NSDate {...}`

Comment: Not yet. There are a few detailed answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720497/swift-do-try-catch-syntax).

Comment: It's very close, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77739128/5623035)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Swift, instead of throwing a specific type, you catch specific types, like this:

```
do {
   let date = try nextOrderDate() 
} catch let error as OrderError {
   print("order error")
} catch {
   print("unexpected error")
}
```

A workaround that I have seen many times, is to return the error instead (very often seen in completion blocks):

```
class func nextOrderDate() -> (NSDate?, OrderError?)
```

**SWIFT 5**

You can now use the [Result](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) enum:

```
class func nextOrderDate() -> Result<NSDate, OrderError>
```

you would usually do sometyhing like:

```
switch nextOrderDate() {
case .success(let nextDate):
    print(nextDate)
case .failure(let orderError) where orderError is OrderError:
    print("OrderError: \(orderError)")
default:
    print("unexpected error")
}
```