# Throw multiple exceptions in Swift

Tags: swift, exception, error-handling

How could a function throw multiple exceptions?
For instance in Java would be something like this:

```
private Int f(Int data, boolean e)
        throws AException, BException,
        CException {...
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at the "Error handling" chapter in the Swift reference? In Swift, it is just `func f(...) throws` and you do not (and can not!) specify  *which* errors are thrown.

Comment: I think you can specify it in this way: func f()  throws -> YourExceptionType , but only one exception type, I was wondering how to throw multiple.

Comment: No you cannot specify it that way. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @user23 What you're specifying there is the *return* type of the function, which is unrelated to the possible error types that the function can `throw`. In Swift, a throwing function can throw *any* error type that conforms to the `Error` protocol – there's no way to specify specific type(s) of error that can be thrown.

Comment: There was an interesting discussion on why Swift doesn't support being able to specify the type(s) of error that a function can throw here: [Why is 'throws' not type safe in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40718542/2976878)

Answer (score 4):

The language does not supports that, most likely because it is considered an anti-pattern. However with a bit of ingenuity you can have an error case that takes an array of errors:

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case general
    case notFound
    case invalid
    case multiple([MyError])
}

func test() throws {
    throw MyError.multiple([.general, .invalid])
}
```

Comment: THis is clever.  Why do you think they consider it an anti-pattern?