# Swift 2.1 - Error Handling - Multiple Catch is not compiled

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I have a function assignName(name:) which throws an error. When that function is called from a do block with multiple catch, It shows the error as:

```
Errors thrown from here are not handled because the enclosing catch is not exhaustive
```

My Code is:

```
enum PersonError: ErrorType {
    case IsNotAPerson
    case IsNotAGoodPerson
    case IsNotAValidPerson
}

func assignName(name: String?) throws {
    guard name != nil else {
        throw PersonError.IsNotAPerson
    }
    personName = name
}
func catchingSpecificError() {
    do {
        try assignName(nil) // Compiler Error displays at this line.

    }catch PersonError.IsNotAPerson {
        print("Propagated error is caught in catch on case .NotAPerson")
    }     
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I just realized this is quite the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720497/swift-do-try-catch-syntax?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include a default catch block (much like when using a switch case) to make your error handling exhaustive; in case the error thrown is not one of the ones you specify.

```
func catchingSpecificError() {
    do {
        try assignName(nil) // Compiler Error displays at this line.

    }catch PersonError.IsNotAPerson {
        print("Propagated error is caught in catch on case .NotAPerson")
    }catch {
        print("default..")
    }
}
```

Slightly off-topic, but I assume `personName = name` refers to a class property `personName` that we cannot see in your example above.

---

With the default `catch` block added, you mention in the comments below that function `catchingSpecificError()` does not cast the error you expect; or rather, the default `catch` block catches your error.

Now, since I don't know the context of your code, I cannot infer what is actually going wrong in your case. I'll post a working example for your below where---in the context of this question---the throw and catch work as expected. Note however that your use of the `guard` block is somewhat out of by convention. Usually you make use of `guard` just like `if let` blocks, i.e., `guard let name = name else { ..`, which will enter the `guard` block if `name` contains `nil`.

Anyway, consider the following fully working example:

```
enum PersonError: ErrorType {
    case IsNotAPerson
    case IsNotAGoodPerson
    case IsNotAValidPerson
}

class Person {
    var personName : String? = ""

    func assignName(name: String?) throws {
        guard name != nil else {
            throw PersonError.IsNotAPerson
        }

        personName = name
    }

    func catchingSpecificError() {
        do {
            try assignName(nil)

        }catch PersonError.IsNotAPerson {
            print("Propagated error is caught in catch on case .NotAPerson")
        }catch {
            print("default..")
        }
    }
}

var myPerson = Person()
var myName : String? = nil

myPerson.catchingSpecificError()
/* Prints: "Propagated error is caught in catch on case .NotAPerson" */
```

As expected, we catch `PersonError.IsNotAPerson` thrown by function `assignName`. Hopefully you can make use of this example your get your own code (the parts that you haven't shown us in your question) working.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with default catch. In my case, The throwing methods assignName(nil) throws PersonError.IsNotAPerson error, But the default catch is executed, not the catch I specifically should catch the PersonError.IsNotAPerson error.

Comment: @ShanmugarajaG Happy to help. I added an example for you, hopefully you can compare this with your own implementation (that you haven't shown us) and see why your case doesn't work as intended. If you still get unexpected results, possibly add more details to your question.

Comment: Thanks, It worked, Instead of passing nil to the assignName(), I passed a parameter with type String? and value is nil. It worked yaar.