# How do I find out the exact error in catch block

Tags: swift

I have this swift beauty:

```
do {
    let path = "/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/hello.txt"
    let str = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    print(str)
} catch {
    print("shit happens")
}
```

Of course I am getting the error message because there's an error. How can I find out what the error is? (yes, the file exists)

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID419

Comment: Closely related: [Swift error handling - determining the error type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524125/) (possible duplicate, I'm uncertain in this case; the linked thread does not contain an answer making use of Eric D.:s `NSError.localizedDescription` method below).

Comment: @dfri I've had a surprising hard time for 5 mins to try and find a good duplicate. I've decided to answer anyway, maybe I'll be able to close it to a good target later...

Comment: @EricD. Both the two duplicates we've discussed in the last 30 mins or so are ones I've participated in as an answerer, hence the ease for me to find these, so not a fair comparison :) Without that, I find it difficult to find duplicates for some questions (which hopefully some one that actually participated in those duplicates will find, later on :) ). I didn't know about `NSError.localizedDescription`, so I think your answer below brings additional value, maybe later duplicate linking can be appropriate, but for now I say let's leave it.

Answer (score 2):

Make `catch` create an "error" constant for you, compatible with NSError:

```
do {
    let path = "/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/hello.txt"
    let str = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print(str)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

You can also just use `catch` which *automatically* creates an "error" constant:

```
do {
    let path = "/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/hello.txt"
    let str = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print(str)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I find it really frustrating that this simple fact is not mentioned in Apple's Swift book under the error handling part.