# How to have Error Type inference for a throwing function in a protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

Is there a way to create a throwing function with a specified `Error` sub type that will be thrown? Below code is an example of how I'd like it to be.

```
protocol ValidatorError: Error {
    var somePrintableThingy: String { get }
}

protocol Validator {
    associatedType T
    var model: T { get set }

    init(model: T)

    func validate() throws where Error: ValidatorError
}
```

Example Use Case

```
class SomeModelErrorNotValidatorError: Error {
    case invalidUsername
}

class SomeModelError: ValidatorError {
    case invalidUsername

    var somePrintableThingy: String {
        switch self { case .invalidUsername: return "haha" }
    }
}

class SomeModel {
    var username: String = ""
    init(username: String) { self.username = username }
}

class SomeModelValidator: Validator {
    var model: SomeModel

    init(model: SomeModel) { self.model = model }

    func validate() throws {
        guard self.model.username.isEmpty else {
            // this line should be fine
            throw SomeModelError.invalidUsername

            // if i replace it with this line it should not be fine
            throw SomeModelErrorNotValidatorError.invalidUsername
        }
    }
}

class SomeModelViewController: UIViewController {
    // .. some other codes here
    func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any? = nil) {
        let model = SomeModel(username: self.txtUsername.text ?? "")
        let validator = SomeModelValidator(model: model)

        do {
            try validator.validate()
        } catch let error { 
            // since I already know that this is a `SomeModelError`
            // I could just do this 
            print(error.somePrintableThingy)
        }
    }
}
```

**PS:** The possible workaround for this is to create a non throwing function with a *callback* but I don't want to do that

**PS PS:** Another possible workaround for this would be to use a linting tool, but that's too much.

Comment: Do you want all objects that conforms to Validator be able to call validate() and throw ValidatorError right away? Without any validation process?

Comment: No, what I want is to explicitly state (defensive coding) that `validate()` can only throw an `Error` of type `ValidatorError`

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: It seems that its impossible in current Swift 4 version. You cannot specify ErrorType in throw. Going from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720497/swift-do-try-catch-syntax

Comment: That [so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720497/swift-do-try-catch-syntax) you added actually had an answer that answered by question. [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30800597/5928180)